# Conversion of LONG to Timestamp in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have a data source which is sending TIMESTAMP data in LONG integer format and we have to convert it into TIMESTAMP in Oracle. I can do it in JAVA very easily. However, I am not sure how can this be achieved in ORACLE. TO_TIMESTAMP is giving invalid month error.

```
Sample data - 1636070400000
```

**Java snippet**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      long timeStamp = 1636070400000L;
        Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(timeStamp);
      System.out.println("Timestamp is "+stamp);
    }
}
```

Above snippet returns - 2021-11-05 00:00:00.0

I want output in similar format in SQL to manipulate the data further (YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value seems to be Java/Javascript timestamp, i.e. number of Millisecond from 1970-01-01. Try this one:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + 1636070400000/1000 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND
FROM dual;
```

It returns UTC time. If you like to get your local time, then use

```
SELECT (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + 1636070400000/1000 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AT LOCAL
FROM dual;
```

or

```
SELECT (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + 1636070400000/1000 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AT 'Europe/Zurich'
FROM dual;
```

Instead of `INTERVAL` literal, you can also use `NUMTODSINTERVAL(1636070400000/1000, 'second')`

Comment: its my current code from work we use : to_date('01/01/1970','dd/mm/yyyy') + (1636070400000 / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))

Comment: @AliFidanli That's also fine. However, the result is given as UTC time. If you like to get local time, then result is wrong. By using `TO_DATE` you also loose fractional seconds, which might be required.

Comment: totally aggreed. just wanted to share  it when saw the question :)